# Can Fuse ESB receive message from TIBCO rendezvous?

Tags: esb, fuseesb

I wanted to know the different methods Fuse ESB can read a message from the TIBCO rendezvous channel.

Regards,
Arun Lakhotia

Answer (score 0):

Fuse ESB supports messaging using JMS (its a Java Messaging Specification). TIBCO supports JMS as well, and therefore you can integrate Fuse ESB with Tibco (using JMS).

Comment: RV is being used by the client and do not want to replace it as there are many consumers to it. What is the best mode to invoke FUSE routers considering a java wrapper will be written to read the message from RV bus.